ML V REML for Hypothesis Testing
I am curious about doing hypothesis testing with REML values via a likelihood ratio test, or whatever test would make sense for REML values, but these two highly upvoted answers to existing cross validated questions seem to give contradictory answers.
This answer seems to recommend that REML is used, while this answer seems to say REML should essentially never be used.
Are these two answers contradicting each other?  If not, what is different about the context of the two problems that makes them each correct respectively?

In the comments section of the first answer you can read that regarding the recommendation for using REML for model comparison, "your nested models need to have the same variables with fixed effects" (written by the author of the answer). The second answer says: "you cannot compare models that differ in fixed effects if they are fitted by REML rather than ML". This is basically the same statement. (In particular, the second answer certainly does not say that "REML should essentially never be used".)

oh okay. thank you.  Does this mean the p-value calculated with REML is identical to that calculated with ML?

@AFriendlyFish I don't think so. In many cases both of these are valid, but they're not the same.

I believe you, but that sounds a little crazy to me.  Consider I simulate null data.  Presumably both  REML and ML reject 5%, but the 5% they reject are generally different, what's going on with the datasets they disagree on?  Is it really an arbitrary choice which method I decide to trust (I know the two methods have the not arbitrary advantages and disadvantages listed in the other answers)  I suppose the best approach is to try both tests for my specific data generating process and see which gives the results that I like more for my specific context?

@AFriendlyFish Significance thresholds are rather arbitrary, and in fact a p-value of 0.045 isn't really very different from a p-value of 0.06. The message of the data cannot really be appropriately boiled down to a binary "accept/reject" decision, and if you apply two things that are slightly different, you may well get slightly different results. If you want to know more about this, look around, there are related questions on CV, or you may ask your own.
